# Intuitive explanation for variance of vector

Tags: variance, covariance

I am reading about variance and covariance of vectors.

The variance of vector $X$ is defined as:   $$\frac{X^T X}{n-1}.$$

The co-variance of the vectors $X$ and $Y$ is defined as: $$\frac{X^T Y}{n-1}.$$

I could wrap my head around co-variance :-).

It could be seen as dot product of vector $X$ and $Y$.

The dot product is zero when the vectors are orthogonal (so not co-related at all).

The dot product is $1$ when the vectors are parallel (highly co-related).

But I am not able to understand how the dot product of a vector with itself signifies variance.

Comment: The dot product of  $X$ and $Y$ is not $1$ "when the vectors are parallel", as it depends on the length of the vectors: you may be mixing covariance and correlation.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$I just want to address four subtleties which I think might help you understand this better, although I am not entirely certain if they answer your question. If they do, they would only do so indirectly.

In any case, it seems that making sure you are clear about how these concepts apply to your situation seems to me likely a prerequisite for being able to phrase the question in a way that conveys clearly to others where the precise/exact source of your confusion lies.

**1.** Correlation is "normalized covariance". (Normalized means re-scaled to a standard, i.e. "normal", size, thus making it easier to compare apples and oranges, by making them equally-sized fruits.)

Wikipedia [has a nice page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_correlation) about how the two quantities differ and how they are similar.

**2.** There is an important distinction between a random variable $X$ and its expected value, $\E X$. The latter, $\E X$, is an attempt to take the "average" of all possible values of the former, $X$.

[This document (page 4)](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/g-expectation.pdf) has a nice section about the geometric interpretation of expectation -- it is extremely similar (arguably in some way the same) as the notion of integral in calculus, which one often thinks of in terms of the area underneath a graph.

**3.** The difference between perfect, theoretical population parameters and the values we *estimate* for those quantities based on a limited, finite amount of (possibly slightly incorrect) sample data.

The [Wikipedia article about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) seems readable to me and less technical than most similar articles, so you might find it a good place to start reading about the topic.

In particular, as mentioned in the comments on this answer, it appears that you are working with *estimators* for the variance/covariance. This is different from the actual "perfect, theoretical" quantities themselves -- it can be convenient sometimes to blur the distinction between a statistic and its estimator, but it is also important to always remember the difference and keep it in mind.

**4.** The difference between *centered* and *uncentered* statistics. It looks like you are using estimators for uncentered quantities (unless we know a priori that $\E X = 0 \E Y$ -- this is *not* true in general), which is problematic in particular since the variance and covariance are *centered* statistics.

In particular, how you might interpret the variance and/or covariance geometrically (for example, as "spread" of the distribution) depends crucially on the fact that they are centered about the expectation/mean of the random variables involved.

[This page](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Variance.html) gives a nice example interpreting the variance in a specific case as "the moment of inertia of the mass distributed about the center of mass" -- such a quantity makes much less sense without already specifying in advance where the "center of mass" lies.

Comment: (1) The formula with $1/(n-1)$ indicates these vectors represent *data* and we're talking about an *estimator* of covariance. (2) Since part of the OP's confusion may revolve around the difference between centered and uncentered data, it looks important to include that concept in your description of "normalization." In fact, correlation is covariance of *standardized* (centered, scaled) values.

Comment: @whuber I agree with you entirely -- I should have mentioned in my answer the difference between centered and uncentered values -- it occurred to me only after writing this how important this is, since imo the centeredness of the variance/covariance statistic is crucial to any proper heuristic interpretation. I will update my answer accordingly.